# Need option to see larger versions of images in questions

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

An image included in a question is not helpful because you can't enlarge it to see the detail.

The image in this question is a perfect example:
[How i can display article filter by age in ee2?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13991/how-i-can-display-article-filter-by-age-in-ee2)

Can you guys add functionality so we can see the original image in an overlay/popup when the smaller thumbnail is clicked?

Comment: Right click image -> Open image in new tab ;)

Comment: Arguably, the OP should crop the image to show the relevant parts. Most of that image can go.

Comment: Yes, agreed it should be cropped... But as is there isn't an obvious SE way to see the larger image... Right clicking on the image and selecting View Image worked for me in FireFox. Not an ideal solution as people won't always know that option exists (like me!). IMO, it would a better UX if you clicked on the image and were presented with larger version.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under "post only the relevant information" - the user should really do more work on an image so it contains the relevant information only.

There is also an easy work around to the lack of interface - Right click image -> Open image in new tab.

For these reasons I am declining the feature request.